# Modifications to wp plugin deleted after a few days

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small wordpress (4.3.2) website and for the contact form I have used the free version of the Contact Bank plugin.

I have modified the one of the plugin's files (contact_bank_forms.php) located in /wp-content/plugins/contact-bank/frontend_views/ and everything looked good.

But after a few days I have noticed that every modification i made to this file was lost and realised that it went back to the original code - like I have not modified anything.

I reuploaded my modifications but it seems that every few days it goes back to the original one.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: check this if that can help you in customizing the plugin https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/child-plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has automatic updates (https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates).

You can either disable them with config constant

`define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );`

Or write own plugin that will alter existing one.

Comment: Most likely reason, and I second writing your own plugin for the modification.

Comment: Yep.  For security it's always good to have your updates on.  Keeping everything current is great. Always use your own plugins for mods.  Otherwise you'll be making those edits a lot.